# How do I use micro-state accounting in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, performance, operating-system

I would like to access micro-state accounting timers programmatically on Linux. I guess the first part of the question is where are these available? Which kernel versions and distros? Which hardware platforms? The second part is how to actually go about accessing the timers? What is the system call?

Here is a (somewhat old) page [describing micro-state accounting](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/IA64wiki/MicroStateAccounting), but I couldn't find the system call described there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patches and user-space programs are available at http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/patches/. As the patches did not migrate upstream, [seemingly because of too high complexity/overhead](http://www.uwsg.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0503.1/1190.html), you'll have to roll your own kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Searching for MSA_SELF on google shows that it was last discussed years ago, and a quick look upstream shows that it isn't in the upstream kernel. So I think it's fair to say "this data isn't available".

You might want to look at clock_getres() etc.